# How to retrieve Imported Namespaces in a CodeActivity?

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-activity

Is there any way to programmatically retrieve `Imported Namespaces` collection of the workflow from within a custom `Activity`?
I would need to use the imports in the `Execute` method of my `CodeActivity`:

[image]

I know that from the `workflow designer` or `activity designer` level I could use:

```
workflowDesigner.Context.Items.GetValue<ImportedNamespaceContextItem>().ImportedNamespaces
```

however, I am not sure if direct references to `workflow designer` from the `Activity` is a good practice.
And if it will work when executing the workflow.